# Subtract and Sum Operations On Columns

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have an output like this:

```
Volume               c1                     c2
--------------------------------------------------
0                   1000                     0
1-20                 100                    10
20+                   50                    40
```

I get this output by this:

```
SELECT 
case when volume=0 then '0' when volume <21 then '1-20' when volume>=21 then '21+' as Volume,
sum(ab) as c1,
sum(xy) as c2
FROM 
table t
GROUP BY
case when volume=0 then '0' when volume <21 then '1-20' when volume>=21 then '21+'
```

However, I need to get the output just like below. I am trying to subtract sum of c1 column from sum of c2 column and result must be placed at first row under c2 column just like this:

```
Volume                c1                  c2
--------------------------------------------------
0                   1000                **1100**
1-20                 100                  10
20+                   50                  40
```

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you elaborate ?

Comment: Please show sample data - it's not clear what "I am trying to subtract sum of C1..." means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply do:

```
SELECT (case when volume = 0 then '0' when volume < 21 then '1-20' when volume>=21 then '21+' end) as Volume,
       sum(ab) as c1,
       (case when volume = 0
             then sum(sum(ab)) over () - sum(sum(xy))
             else sum(xy)
       end) as c2
FROM  table t
GROUP BY (case when volume=0 then '0' when volume <21 then '1-20' when volume>=21 then '21+' end);
```

Subqueries and CTEs are unnecessary when you can simply use window functions.

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH x
AS
(
  SELECT 
    case when volume=0 then '0' when volume <21 then '1-20' when volume>=21 then '21+' as Volume,
    sum(ab) as c1,
    sum(xy) as c2
  FROM 
    table t
  GROUP BY
    CASE when volume=0 then '0' when volume <21 then '1-20' when volume>=21 then '21+'
)
SELECT x.Volume, x.c1, (CASE WHEN x.Volume = 0 
                             THEN (SELECT SUM(x2.c1 - x2.c2) 
                                   FROM x AS x2) 
                             ELSE x.c2 END)
FROM x
```

Answer (score 0):

You can used below query to get output you required
with CTE table expression you can achieved.

with Cte as(
SELECT 
case when volume=0 then '0' when volume <21 then '1-20' when volume>=21 then '21+' as Volume,
sum(ab) as c1,
sum(xy) as c2,
sum(ab)-sum(xy) as c
FROM 
table t
GROUP BY
case when volume=0 then '0' when volume <21 then '1-20' when volume>=21 then '21+' end
)

select volume,c1, case when Volume ='0' then (select sum(c3) from cte) else c2 end c2 from cte